# JetBrains AppCode - IDE is indexing user directory

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, indexing, appcode

I have an iOS-Project depending on a library which is located in `~/Library/flutter/...`

- Using **Xcode**: Everything is going well.
- Using **AppCode** from JetBrains: The IDE wants to index all files located in `~/...`. (there are tons)

*Possible Solution:* I can exclude all directories except `/Library` and further exclude everything except `/Library/flutter` (Still, there are tons of files to index)

I would prefer a less time consuming way.

---

Any help is very much appreciated!

Generally, I love JetBrains